# Facebook Connect works offline, but not online "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

Access to my developed website is done using facebook connect.

Everything is OK offline, but not online. I get a navigation error (using Chrome) "This webpage has a redirect loop" :

The webpage at **[https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=209633612480053&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluward.com%2Faccess%2Flogin_facebook&state=299262ddf89afbf382452df89c9a2ce8&scope=email%2C+user_birthday%2C+user_about_me%2C+user_location%2C+publish_stream&fbconnect=1#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=209633612480053&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluward.com%2Faccess%2Flogin_facebook&state=299262ddf89afbf382452df89c9a2ce8&scope=email%2C+user_birthday%2C+user_about_me%2C+user_location%2C+publish_stream&fbconnect=1#_=_)** has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Here is the PHP code (using CodeIgniter framework):

```
public function login()
{
  // Get the FB UID of the currently logged in user
  $uid = $fb->getUser();

  // If the user has already allowed the application, you'll be able to get his/her FB UID
  if($uid) {

     try {
        $profile = $fb->api(array(  
            'method'      => 'users.getinfo',  
            'uids'        => $uid,  
            'fields'      => 'uid, first_name, last_name, pic_square, pic_big, sex, birthday_date, current_location, email'
        ));

        // Only the first user.
        $profile = $profile[0];
     } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        return false;
     }

     // Do stuff when already logged in.

     return $profile;

  } else {

     // If not, let's redirect to the ALLOW page so we can get access
     redirect($this->getLoginUrl(array(
         'scope'           => 'email, user_birthday, user_about_me, user_location, publish_stream',
         'fbconnect'       =>  1
     )));
  }
}
```

And depending on the profile info, I check if the user already exists on database, then log him/her, and if not exists on database, signup him/her.

### Update:

When I clear Facebook cookies, the redirect to login page is successful, and I'm able to fill email/password.

Unfortunately, when I click "log in" button, I get the same error message as I displayed above.

Comment: Can you post the full code you are using for auth please.

Comment: Here is the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does somebody know what the error message means really (is it a cookie problem)? Why does this appears only for online test and not on localhost?

Comment: Updated the question with info from different tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your using and older version? Here is how i would handle issue with php-sdk 3.1.1 "the most current version".

---

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '135669679827333',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$params = array(
  scope => 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,read_friendlists',
  //redirect_uri => $url
  );
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
  echo '<script> top.location.href=\''.$loginUrl.'\'</script>';
};
```

Comment: The strange thing, is that my code works perfectly offline (using localhost), but the same code (just adjusting facebook Site URL) doesn't work online !

Comment: make sure the domain settings in your app settings match.  if you set your app to local host, it has to be local host, else if domain then has to be the domain it is set to.

Comment: This is OK. I set two apps: one for localhost and the other for online use, and I'm sure to use the correct app depending on my test location (localhost or online).